# Can ADO.NET provider for Oracle connect peoplesoft DB too?

Tags: ado.net, synchronization, microsoft-sync-framework, peoplesoft

There is `ADO.NET` `provider/adapter` for `Oracle`. Can I use the same to connect `peoplesoft db` too ?
I want to use it with `Microsoft Sync services`.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

if the underlying PeopleSoft RDBMS is Oracle, then you can... but i think the even bigger problem will be understanding the database schema...